# requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS while running adb shell commands

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-service

I am trying to edit the settings for back gesture scaling on my **Oneplus 9** running **Android 12** on **OxygenOS**. The stock settings don’t let me set limits for the back gesture on the left side of the screen, so I wanted to set it manually.

```
adb shell settings put secure back_gesture_inset_scale_left -1
```

This command successfully limited the gesture like I wanted on *this same device* in Android 10 and 11, but running it now gives me this error.

```
Exception occurred while executing 'put':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Not sure how to address this, I have enabled USB Debugging, Disabled Permissions Monitoring, and still nothing. The device is recognized by adb.

Comment: This started to work in OnePlus 8T after I restarted the phone once

Comment: Restart the phone!

After enabling USB Debugging, Disabling Permissions Monitoring, (and possibly disabling verify apps over USB and disabling Verify bytecode of debuggable apps) you have to restart the phone.  OnePlus 8 oxygenOS 13.1

Answer (score 8):

open the "Developer options -> Disable permission monitoring" toggle.

[image]

Comment: Please add a image description

Comment: I already did that, if you look at the bottom of the post I listed all the developer settings I configured.

Comment: Thanks, I should also note that restart required after enabling this option (tip from OP comment).

Comment: What if this doesn't appear under developer settings. Is there a way to enable it another way? I'm using a Sony XZ2C with Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 and I needed to open "USB debugging (Security settings)" option. [Here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8w5w.png)

Answer (score 0):

Same here, using Redmi Note 11 pro. Turn on following on developer settings' first you may need to create a xiomi account

1.Turn on Install via USB
2.Turn on USB Debugging (Security settings)

https://xdaforums.com/t/i-cant-enable-write_secure_settings-for-an-app-over-adb.3855596/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).